# what is the minimum bottleneck spanning tree here?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

A bit confused about the term minimum bottleneck spanning tree. I thought it was the spanning tree with the cheapest maximum edge, but the example I was given seems to contradict this.

[image]

In the example above, my material says:

> For the given graph G, the above figure illustrates all the spanning trees for the given graph. Among the spanning trees, the minimum spanning tree is the one with weight 3. The Minimum Bottleneck Spanning trees for the graph are the trees with bottleneck edge weight 3.

Shouldn't it be the graph with a bottleneck edge weight of 2 since it minimizes the most expensive edge?

Comment: Yes. Also the same spanning tree is a minimum spanning tree so it has to be a minimum bottleneck spanning tree.

Comment: @Rinkesh P thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree